# What do you call this plant?

Tags: identification

One of our neighbors are in the process of renovating their house and have taken out an old potted plant that they've said they dont want to keep anymore. I asked them about the plant and they didn't know what it was. From the looks of it, it appears neglected. Does anyone know what it's called?[image][image][image][image]

Comment: A Prunus? You have many species too look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Prunus_species , maybe one of the more common species: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus#Species

Comment: Could be an Almond flower, but not sure.

Comment: Could be _Prunus_ but these usually have more prominent lenticular banding. Certainly _Rosaceae_, shoots and leaves look like _Malus_ as do the dormant buds (_Prunus_ are pointier). It's been grafted and there is a sucker emerging from below the graft union.

Comment: Thanks guys. In my region, almond tree is the first to bloom. Around late february. Apple trees are just waking up from dormancy and apricot/nectarine trees have dropped 90% of their blossoms. With that being said, is it safe to assume that it's an apricot or nectarine tree?

Comment: @george of all trades_ which one's the sucker? The cane in green? What do you think it's grafted onto?

Comment: Sucker is the green one, as for what it's grafted on, that will depend on what's usual for your part of the world (you don't actually say, always helpful). _Malus_ are later than most _Prunus_ - just starting to burst bud in my part of the world (Cotswolds, UK). As for assuming what it is, get it healthy and once it fruits you'll definitely know!

Comment: @george of all trades_ it's the same here in my part of the world. Prunus are done flowering and malus have just woken up. Anyways, should i cut off the green one? The leaves on it are very similar to those on the rest of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recognise the single flower, though someone else might, but the plant's determination to live despite its poor growing conditions probably should be rewarded! It's in way too small a pot, yet is obviously something that wants to get a good size - I'd wait till any flowering is finished, reduce the topgrowth by a third, then try to get it out of that pot - this may prove impossible because of the waisted shape which will prevent the rootball from coming out, so if possible, you will need to break the pot to remove it. Give it another pot (preferably one that isn't waisted, nor narrower at the top than at the bottom) 1-2 sizes larger than the rootball, using new potting soil, water well, watering ongoing as and when it needs it, and see what happens. It likely will respond by putting on new growth, and it may then become more apparent what it actually is, as well as producing more flowers next year, when an accurate ID should be possible.

You could try just planting it in the ground once its out of the pot, but it may be something that gets very large indeed, so it's best to ID it correctly before deciding to plant in the ground.

Comment: @bamboo_ yes your very right. I did take it out though. I had to break the thing because of it's shape. The thing was root bound. So far the assumption is that this is a nectarine/apricot tree since they're the ones that are in their late stage of blooming at this time around in my region that also have a similar appearing to this. Initially i though that this was an almond tree but they woke up late February and i doubt blossoms would remain on the tree this late. It's bizarre how someone would have a plant for so many years and not know what it's called.

Comment: The trouble with plants that have been kept constricted in this way is its quite hard to tell what they are because there's no sensible growth habit, and flowering may be non existent or significantly reduced... as for not knowing what it is, maybe they did once but they've forgotten... It likely is a Prunus of some variety, as you know....and you  may be right re nectarine/apricot. Be interesting to find out!

Comment: If it's easier for you to look after in the ground, then you can always lift after a season or two once it's healthier. Also, if you can't keep it in a pot, and you don't have room for it in the ground, then what are you going to with it?

Comment: @george of all trades_ I've transferred it into a different pot. I do however would prefer to have it in the ground but as bamboo pointed out, it's best to ID it correctly before taking the initiative for we done know how large this thing's going to get.